# Cause: No such property: sourceSets for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention

Tags: groovy, build, build-process, gradle

i have run a code snippet from Gradle Cookbook

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task "create-dirs" << {
   convention.sourceSets.all*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
   convention.sourceSets.all*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
}
```

when i run i am getting following error

```
Cause: No such property: sourceSets for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention
```

i am using Gradle 0.9-rc-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry. i got it

it must be

```
 
apply plugin: 'java'
```

task "create-dirs" << {
   sourceSets.all*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
   sourceSets.all*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
}

Comment: If i need to write my own plugin to create a structure how can i link my structure to sourceSets ?

Answer (score 2):

The property all has been removed now ,So you can do it as:

```
   task "create-dirs" {
        def defaultPackage = "org.akash.gradle";
        ['java', 'groovy', 'resources'].each { String dir ->
           sourceSets*."$dir".srcDirs*.each { dir1 ->
             def newDir = new File(dir1, defaultPackage);
             newDir.mkdirs();
           }
        }
   }
```